# Updating sql db with records from dataframe pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, sql-update

I have a sample database with five columns and five rows of data.  The first two columns are unique for every row.  Some of the cells in the database are intentionally empty.

I have a dataframe with the same sequence of columns, names, etc as in the database, but all the cells in the dataframe are filled with data.

I want to avoid deleting the db table and uploading the dataframe in its place and, instead, via sqlalchemy or any other method, loop through the dataframe and update the data in the database accordingly.

Here are some of my multiple attempts to create the loop to accomplish that none of which worked and all which threw different errors:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.Index)
    for col in df.columns[1:]:
        print(getattr(row, col))

mytable = db.Table('daily_admits_test', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
for col in update.columns:
    for idx, row in update.iterrows():
        print(f'{col} = {row[col]}')
        print(row[0], row[3], row[1])
        query = db.update(mytable).values(col = row[col])
        query = query.where(mytable.columns.client_id == row[0] and 
         mytable.columns.Transfer_Date == row[3] and mytable.columns.fac_id == row[1])
        results = con.execute(query)
```

This worked to update a single record, but required hard coding the variables as you can see in the second query line.  Won't work:

```
mytable = db.Table('daily_admits_test', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = db.update(mytable).values(Patient_Name = '')
# query = query.where(mytable.columns.client_id == '936042')
query = query.where(mytable.columns.client_id == '936042' and mytable.columns.Transfer_Date == '2022-01-04' and mytable.columns.fac_id == 22)
results = con.execute(query)
```

The goal seems simple.  Iterate over my dataframe and only update the corresponding sql db columns where the values in the dataframe differ from those in the database.  I really appreciate you taking a look at this.  I have spent hours on SO, the internet in general, tried many approaches and nothing is working.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just fully replace all the data?

Comment: I wary of doing that in case a full replace errors for some reason and I lose all the data.

Comment: what is the source of your dataframe data, an API or something?

Comment: The source is in an Excel workbook which employees enter data into and then I’m trying to preserve in a database but only update the values that they change in the workbook.

Comment: Create an external table that is linked to the worksheet instead.

Comment: Whether you create copies of the workbook, back-up your database whatever solution you choose (which is a separate issue)... I would not advise what you are doing in your code above. I would just do a full replace of the data. I think your code is overcomplicating everything, and I would focus more on processes to backup and secure records of your data. For example, in Google Sheets, you can access previous versions of files... I'm sure you could do that with excel online as well. tldr this isn't really a python problem -- you should just fully replace the data.

Comment: the main reason not to do a full replace is usually for performance if you have a table with hundreds of millions of rows and only want to add like a million rows from the previous day's data or something and do a full update once a month. But, since you have an excel workbook, this is not an issue b/c it should take seconds/minutes to send to the db.